# How to match, but not capture, part of a regex with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds

I have a line in a text doc that im trying to pull data from.

Example

- Line im searching for in Text file:
  ***Valid from: Sun May 17 19:00:00 CDT 1998***

I want to find the key words "***Valid from:***" and then get only ***Sun May 17*** and ***1998***

So end result should look like this:

- ***Sun May 17 1998***

I think im close to getting it right. This is what I have. It finds the keyword ***Valid From:*** but it returns more than I need

- ***Sun May 17 19:00:00 CDT 1998***
- ***(?<=Valid from:)\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+***

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two [capture groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions) `(…)` instead of lookaround construct:

```sh
$sampleText = 'Valid from: Sun May 17 19:00:00 CDT 1998'
$regEx = 'Valid from:\s+(\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+)\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+(\d+)'

if( $sampleText -match $regEx ) {
    # Combine the matched values of both capture groups into a single string
    $matches[1,2] -join ' '
}
```

Output:

```text
Sun May 17 1998
```

- If the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch) operator successfully matches the pattern on the right-hand-side with the input text on the left-hand-side, the automatic variable `$matches` is set.
- `$matches` contains the full match at index 0 and the matched values of any capture groups at subsequent indices, in this case 1 and 2.
- Using the `-join` operator we combine the matched values of the capture groups into a single string.
- [Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7ooXOd/1).